# Probability of Probabilities :)

Tags: probability

So here is a tough one (or so i think). i have 15 games (30 teams). and only 2 options i can chose from (even / odd number of goals). I want to bet a ticket with each possible combination. How many tickets will I have to bet ? I want to have all 15 games on the ticket.

I would like to know all the possible outcomes. The number of tickets i will have to bet on.

Thank you very much.

Comment: tried all odd, all even, then 1 even, 14 odd, then lower the 1 even and put 14 other odds, and so on...then 2 even, 3 even,,,etc....

Comment: i also did 2 matches, 4 options to bet on and i did 2x2x2x2 = 16...

Comment: but this is 15 matches, 2 options (even/odd) so is it 15x15 , or is it 2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2 ?

Comment: $15$ matches, $2^{15}$ tickets.

Comment: 32,768 tickets....

Comment: Yes, $32768$, enough to wallpaper a room. You are sure to win, and also sure to lose money, since the payoff for a winning ticket is undoubtedly much less than $32000$ to $1$.

Comment: on my first try, i just randomly selected 15 matches. 3 results were wrong. :-/